# not showing image in the design view

Tags: android

here is my xml file for showing images in design view.i added the picture in drawable folder.but its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/german"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/german"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post complete layout .

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/german"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/german"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in your xml file is there any other code or only this much

Comment: this LinearLayout is ok no problem with that try to give background color of linearlayout and see it is visible or not with single image

Comment: at which drawable folder you paste the image

Comment: I don't create any folder just follow some steps and then there is folder 'german.png' in which there are 4 different images with same name 'german.png' of diff sizes

Answer (score 0):

Change your `android:layout_height` of `LinearLayout` to **wrap_content**.View with 0dp height will not show.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy to Help and Happy Coding...

Answer (score -1):

You have to do like this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="2" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Surely it would works.